# How to add Label in BWWalkthrough View Controller with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, bwwalkthrough

I use ***BWWalkthrough library*** for slides images in my app. I ***add Title and Message labels*** in each slide.

[image]

I would like to **translate** to each labels.
 
So, I drag the label to `IBOutlet` and I add NStranslation text in `ViewDidLoad`. 
But, when I run the code, I got fatal error.  
 Here is my code. 
In `BWWalkthroughPageViewController.swift` ,

```
  @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle1: UILabel!
```

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lblTitle1.text = NSLocalizedString("Date:", comment: "")

    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    subviewsSpeed = Array()

    for v in view.subviews{
        speed.x += speedVariance.x
        speed.y += speedVariance.y
        if !notAnimatableViews.contains(v.tag) {
            subviewsSpeed.append(speed)
        }
    }
}
```

I got error in these following codes **(BWWalkthroughViewController.swift)**.

```
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and **lblTitle1.text = NSLocalizedString("Date:", comment: "")**

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below, that will add one label in all page, you can add more label like same way.

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let sampleLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    sampleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    sampleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    sampleLabel.text = "Hello this is iOS dev"
    sampleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    sampleLabel.textColor = .red
    sampleLabel.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    sampleLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow

    view.addSubview(sampleLabel)
    sampleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sampleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    sampleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    sampleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleLabel.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    sampleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    subviewsSpeed = Array()

    for v in view.subviews{
        speed.x += speedVariance.x
        speed.y += speedVariance.y
        if !notAnimatableViews.contains(v.tag) {
            subviewsSpeed.append(speed)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can prevent crash to happening by safe unwrapping `lblTitle1` check below.

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (lblTitle1) != nil {
        lblTitle1.text = NSLocalizedString("Date:", comment: "")
    }

    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    subviewsSpeed = Array()

    for v in view.subviews{
        speed.x += speedVariance.x
        speed.y += speedVariance.y
        if !notAnimatableViews.contains(v.tag) {
            subviewsSpeed.append(speed)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know if any issue @MayPhyu

Comment: bro, your first codes work and show in the center of the screen. As my screenshot image, I would like to appear at the bottom. Now, I remove all your previous codes in ViewDidLoad and I tried with your second  code. But, I got error bro

Comment: it work's for me, wait let me update my code @MayPhyu

Comment: bro, I download your project and click on Run. Build Success msg show but could not run. What happen bro?

Comment: it's running on my side, check from your side, clean and build, delete derived data etc... @MayPhyu

Comment: bro, so for other slides, should I check like this ?  if (lblTitle1) != nil {
            lblTitle1.text = NSLocalizedString("Date", comment: "")
        } and  if (lblMsg) != nil {
            lblMsg1.text = NSLocalizedString("Message", comment: "")
        } Just like this bro ?

Comment: @MayPhyu Yes you have to check and safe unwrapping

Comment: bro @iOSDev, bro could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117730/how-to-change-label-color-inside-table-cell-with-swift-3  ?