# How to change label color inside table cell with swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, xcode7, textcolor

I put label inside table cell. I changed the text color into "White" in Attributes inspector. I also changed the label background color into "Green".
When I run the app, the text color does not change into white color but background changed to green. I also put the code.

```
 cell.lblName.textColor = UIColor.white
```

I declare this  **@IBOutlet weak var lblAllowAutoRenew: UILabel!**  in **MediaPackListCell.swift** file.
 
In **TableView.swift**,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "planCell",for: indexPath) as! MediaPackListCell

 cell.lblAllowAutoRenew.textColor = UIColor.white

}
```

Each cell has detail disclosure. 
Nothing is working .... :( 
This case is so strange for me. I dragged the label into UI and select the label and then change the color. But, it does not work.
 
 Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Show how you are initiating your cell, show your entire 'cell for row'.

Comment: Not enough information. It should be simple, and we can't help you unless you show your code.

Comment: @HarshadMadaye, bro I update my question. please could you check this?

Comment: @DuncanC, bro I update my question. please could you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing line below

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "planCell",for: indexPath) as! MediaPackListCell
```

with

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "planCell",for: indexPath) as! Tablecell
```

And make sure you are using right reuse identifier "planCell"
, which you have used for Tablecell.swift

Comment: bro I'm sorry. I wrote wrong name swift file in here. I edit it. Could you anything help me please?

Comment: have you cross checked if you are using right reuse identifier.

Comment: Yes. I found the problem bro. Simple label does not have any problem. But I check the condition in it. For eg. if label value is equal to 1 , then cell.lblAllowAutoRenew.text = "Allow" and if it is not equal to 1, then cell.lblAllowAutoRenew.text = "Not Allow" . The problem occurs at that place.  I also put this code cell.lblAllowAutoRenew.textColor = UIColor.white under each condition. But, it does not work. So, if I remove all that condition, the label appears as I want to be bro.

Comment: Just know the error but haven't known the solution to trick this process. :D